getting ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")) - When connecting to Databricks SQL warehouse from Azure MLS Jupyter notebook
I am trying to extract data from Databricks SQL Warehouse through Azure Machine Learning Notebook using Databricks-SQL-Connector and getting the following error in Jupyter Notebook. I am using the following script:
from databricks import sql
import os

connection = sql.connect(
                        server_hostname = "adb-4285847157798999.17.azuredatabricks.net",
                        http_path = "/sql/1.0/warehouses/37667bb8d1fe23fa",
                        access_token = "<access-token>")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from range(10)")
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
connection.close()

Below is the error i am getting . Please suggest how to solve this as i am new to this.
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:199, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    198 try:
--> 199     sock = connection.create_connection(
    200         (self._dns_host, self.port),
    201         self.timeout,
    202         source_address=self.source_address,
    203         socket_options=self.socket_options,
    204     )
    205 except socket.gaierror as e:

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:60, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     58     raise LocationParseError(f"'{host}', label empty or too long") from None
---> 60 for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     61     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/socket.py:955, in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    954 addrlist = []
--> 955 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    956     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NameResolutionError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:789, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    788 # Make the request on the HTTPConnection object
--> 789 response = self._make_request(
    790     conn,
    791     method,
    792     url,
    793     timeout=timeout_obj,
    794     body=body,
    795     headers=headers,
    796     chunked=chunked,
    797     retries=retries,
    798     response_conn=response_conn,
    799     preload_content=preload_content,
    800     decode_content=decode_content,
    801     **response_kw,
    802 )
    804 # Everything went great!

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:490, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    489         new_e = _wrap_proxy_error(new_e, conn.proxy.scheme)
--> 490     raise new_e
    492 # conn.request() calls http.client.*.request, not the method in
    493 # urllib3.request. It also calls makefile (recv) on the socket.

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:466, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    465 try:
--> 466     self._validate_conn(conn)
    467 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1095, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1094 if conn.is_closed:
-> 1095     conn.connect()
   1097 # TODO revise this, see https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2791

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:693, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    692 sock: socket.socket | ssl.SSLSocket
--> 693 self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
    694 server_hostname: str = self.host

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:206, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    205 except socket.gaierror as e:
--> 206     raise NameResolutionError(self.host, self, e) from e
    207 except SocketTimeout as e:

NameResolutionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f065ff85ea0>: Failed to resolve 'dbstoragej5fibm47ntgqa.blob.core.windows.net' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:667, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    666 try:
--> 667     resp = conn.urlopen(
    668         method=request.method,
    669         url=url,
    670         body=request.body,
    671         headers=request.headers,
    672         redirect=False,
    673         assert_same_host=False,
    674         preload_content=False,
    675         decode_content=False,
    676         retries=self.max_retries,
    677         timeout=timeout,
    678         chunked=chunked,
    679     )
    681 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:873, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    870     log.warning(
    871         "Retrying (%r) after connection broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url
    872     )
--> 873     return self.urlopen(
    874         method,
    875         url,
    876         body,
    877         headers,
    878         retries,
    879         redirect,
    880         assert_same_host,
    881         timeout=timeout,
    882         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    883         release_conn=release_conn,
    884         chunked=chunked,
    885         body_pos=body_pos,
    886         preload_content=preload_content,
    887         decode_content=decode_content,
    888         **response_kw,
    889     )
    891 # Handle redirect?

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:873, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    870     log.warning(
    871         "Retrying (%r) after connection broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url
    872     )
--> 873     return self.urlopen(
    874         method,
    875         url,
    876         body,
    877         headers,
    878         retries,
    879         redirect,
    880         assert_same_host,
    881         timeout=timeout,
    882         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    883         release_conn=release_conn,
    884         chunked=chunked,
    885         body_pos=body_pos,
    886         preload_content=preload_content,
    887         decode_content=decode_content,
    888         **response_kw,
    889     )
    891 # Handle redirect?

    [... skipping similar frames: HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen at line 873 (2 times)]

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:873, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    870     log.warning(
    871         "Retrying (%r) after connection broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url
    872     )
--> 873     return self.urlopen(
    874         method,
    875         url,
    876         body,
    877         headers,
    878         retries,
    879         redirect,
    880         assert_same_host,
    881         timeout=timeout,
    882         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    883         release_conn=release_conn,
    884         chunked=chunked,
    885         body_pos=body_pos,
    886         preload_content=preload_content,
    887         decode_content=decode_content,
    888         **response_kw,
    889     )
    891 # Handle redirect?

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:843, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    841     new_e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", new_e)
--> 843 retries = retries.increment(
    844     method, url, error=new_e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    845 )
    846 retries.sleep()

File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py:519, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    518     reason = error or ResponseError(cause)
--> 519     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    521 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dbstoragej5fibm47ntgqa.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /jobs/4285847157799137/sql/2024-12-19/14/results_2024-12-19T14:41:23Z_c0096a00-d0d4-450e-934f-f1ed607087ea?sig=vMkEoWgwiFZTQvCPve8bdNRwveQcepSL5GC8t8Biczc%3D&se=2024-12-19T14%3A56%3A24Z&sv=2019-02-02&spr=https&sp=r&sr=b (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f065ff85ea0>: Failed to resolve 'dbstoragej5fibm47ntgqa.blob.core.windows.net' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/nps/lib/python3.10/s


Follow the below step by step process to achieve your requirement.
Open Notebook in Azure ML workspace and install the databricks connector as shown below.
pip install databricks-sql-connector

After installing it, restart the kernel once to reflect the updated packages.
Then use the same code and you can see It got worked for me.

The above might arise when the databricks-connect version conflicts with the Pyspark version. You can try the troubleshooting steps like changing the compute and re-installing the total package after uninstalling the current Pyspark.
Reference:
# Troubleshooting Databricks Connect for Python
